# C++ plus VS plus WORKFLOW?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, architecture, workflow

I have seen there is Workflow Foundation for .NET. Is there some kind of a tool for creating work flow with C++ on VS? Or there maybe there are similar tools which helps to architect application business processes? Thanks in advance ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating workflows can be done in the Visual Studio Designer.

For architecting applications you should look at Visual Studio Architect Edition

http://ajdotnet.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/visual-studio-2010-architecture-edition/

You can download the Beta 2 version from here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dd582936.aspx